# shapeless convert case class to HList and skip all option fields

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the next class:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[Int], b: Option[String], c: Option[Double])
```

as you can see, all fields is optional, i want convert this class into HList or Tuple, like

```
val f1 = Foo(Some(1) , None, Some(3D))
val f2 = Foo(None, "foo")

val result1 = f1.to[Int::Double::HNil] // => 1::3D
val result2 = f2.to[String::HNil] // "foo"
```

is it possible, without reflection?

Comment: What do you want to happen in e.g. the `f1.to[String :: HNil]` case? It's certainly possible to do this, but you'll need to decide how to handle the case where missing-ness is only known at runtime.

Comment: i think - exception, but possible return Option[T <: HList] like in shapeless `cast` , and in case `f1.to[String :: HNil]` return None

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible to do this with existing type classes in Shapeless (something like `NatTRel` and `RemoveAll`), but I'm not 100% sure of that, and this is a case where I'd just write my own type class:

```
import shapeless._

trait OptionalPieces[L <: HList, S <: HList] {
  def apply(l: L): Option[S]
}

object OptionalPieces extends LowPriorityOptionalPieces {
  implicit val hnilOptionalPieces: OptionalPieces[HNil, HNil] =
    new OptionalPieces[HNil, HNil] {
      def apply(l: HNil): Option[HNil] = Some(HNil)
    }

  implicit def hconsOptionalPiecesMatch[H, T <: HList, S <: HList](implicit
    opt: OptionalPieces[T, S]
  ): OptionalPieces[Option[H] :: T, H :: S] =
    new OptionalPieces[Option[H] :: T, H :: S] {
      def apply(l: Option[H] :: T): Option[H :: S] = for {
        h <- l.head
        t <- opt(l.tail)
      } yield h :: t
    }
}

sealed class LowPriorityOptionalPieces {
  implicit def hconsOptionalPiecesNoMatch[H, T <: HList, S <: HList](implicit
    opt: OptionalPieces[T, S]
  ): OptionalPieces[Option[H] :: T, S] =
    new OptionalPieces[Option[H] :: T, S] {
      def apply(l: Option[H] :: T): Option[S] = opt(l.tail)
    }
}
```

This witnesses that `L` contains *at least* all of the elements of `S` wrapped in `Option`, in order, and gives you a way to unwrap them at runtime (safely).

We can then define a syntax helper class like this:

```
implicit class OptionalPiecesSyntax[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, R]
) {
  def to[S <: HList](implicit op: OptionalPieces[gen.Repr, S]): Option[S] =
    op(gen.to(a))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val f1 = Foo(Some(1) , None, Some(3D))
f1: Foo = Foo(Some(1),None,Some(3.0))

scala> val f2 = Foo(None, Some("foo"), None)
f2: Foo = Foo(None,Some(foo),None)

scala> val result1 = f1.to[Int :: Double :: HNil]
result1: Option[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Double,shapeless.HNil]]] = Some(1 :: 3.0 :: HNil)

scala> val result2 = f2.to[String :: HNil]
result2: Option[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]] = Some(foo :: HNil)
```

If you really wanted exceptions, you could just call `.get` in the syntax class, but that seems like a bad idea.